# Add subview programmatically using instance method

Tags: ios, objective-c, view

I am trying to add a subview programmatically to my `ViewController : UIViewController` by using a method declared in my `ThirdClass : NSObject` class. Here is my code:

In the ViewController.m file I do:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    ThirdClass *instanceOfThirdClass = [[ThirdClass alloc] init];
    [instanceOfThirdClass createView];
}
```

And in my ThirdClass.m I declare the instance method:

```
-(void)createView{
    NSLog(@"enter create app");
    UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 0, 320, 100)];
    [myView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    ViewController *instanceOfViewController = [[ViewController alloc]init];
    [instanceOfViewController.view addSubview:myView];

    }
```

so the problem apparently is that I was trying to add the created view to the class instance, the correct way to do it is the one posted by @gary-riches below,

Comment: You are calling [instanceOfThirdClass createView]; but the method name is createApp. Get your example straight and then we can continue. You also haven't said what's not working. Is it complain that your method names are wrong (they are). Is it failing silently? Is it not finding the method?

Comment: `createView` vs. `createApp` ?

Comment: Apart from calling the wrong method, you are not adding the subview to the intended object's view. Rather than creating an object of _ViewController_ in _ThirdClass.m_ and then adding subview to it, return the _myView_ to receiver and then add subview.

Comment: sorry for the mistake, This is not The actual code that I am using and I have changed and eliminated  as much as possible to simplify the question

Comment: I see you've edit the question. You are attaching the view you create to a new instantiated view controller, but the view you are displaying is that of the one belonging ViewController.m. You need to add the view to the ViewController.m's view.

Comment: I have edited the code now in the question, once again sorry and thanks for notice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are attaching the view you create to a new instantiated view controller, but the view you are displaying is that of the one belonging ViewController.m. You need to add the view to the ViewController.m's view.

Update your createView method to handle a view:

```
-(void)createViewInView:(UIView *)aView{
    NSLog(@"enter create app");
    UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 0, 320, 100)];
    [myView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [aView addSubview:myView];
}
```

Then change your call to be:

```
[instanceOfThirdClass createViewInView:self.view];
```

Also, make sure you have the method signature in the header of ThirdClass.h. It should be:

```
-(void)createViewInView:(UIView *)aView;
```

Comment: I has a method signature in the .h file but apparently it wasn't the right way to add the view to the instance of the class

Comment: Good answer (voted). Laur, you're going to need to post the relevant section of your header (from ThirdClass.h) and your new `createViewInView` method if you need help making Gary's solution work.